# Why does MutationObserver not recognize the xlink:href attribute in the attributeFilter array?

Tags: javascript, svg, mutation-observers

I cannot get a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to pick up changes to just `xlink:href` attributes on the `<use>` element. I have configured a MutationObserver to only watch for a specific attribute change anywhere in the DOM subtree. Here is some context on how that works:

*Note: The code snippets on this page may take a moment to load since they are firing up MutationObservers*

## Using MutationObserver to watch specific attributes:

It is easy to watch for only specific attributes changed in the DOM by specifying which attributes to watch for in the MutationObserver's config object.

```
attributeFilter: ['class']
```

By doing something like the above, you would only trigger the callback when a `class` attribute changes. Here is a more full example where two attributes are being changed on a `div`, but only 1 mutation is logged to the console:

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log('Mutation Type:', mutation.type, 'Attribute:', mutation.attributeName);
  });
});

observer.observe(document.body, {subtree: true, attributes: true, attributeFilter: ['class']});

var myDiv = document.querySelector('#myDiv');
// Logs only one attribute changes (class)
myDiv.className = 'foo';
myDiv.dataset.test = 'foo';

console.log('One mutation will be logged:');
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

---

## MutationObserver does not work with xlink:href

I tried to place the attribute `xlink:href` as the only item in the filter, but I was surprised when I didn't see any mutations logged. I even made sure to use the namespaced `setAttribute` call (`setAttributeNS(...)`):

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation);
  });
});

observer.observe(document.body, {
  subtree: true,
  attributes: true,
  attributeFilter: ['xlink:href']
});

// change the use shape to a circle
document.querySelector('#shape').setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', '#circle');

console.log('No mutations will be logged');
```

```html
<svg display="none">
  <rect id="rect" height="30" width="30" fill="red"></rect>
  <circle id="circle" r="15" cx="15" cy="15" fill="red"></circle>
</svg>

<svg>
  <use id="shape" xlink:href="#rect"></use>
</svg>
```

---

## MutationObserver *does* pick up the change if xlink:href *is not* listed in the filter:

I decided to see if the MutationObserver would log the change if nothing was in the filter, and it did:

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mut) {
    console.log(mut.type, mut.attributeName, mut.attributeNamespace);
  });
});

observer.observe(document.body, {
  subtree: true,
  attributes: true
  // Do not use the attributeFilter option
});

// change the use shape to a circle
document.querySelector('#shape').setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', '#circle');

console.log('One mutation will be logged:')
```

```html
<svg display="none">
  <rect id="rect" height="30" width="30" fill="red"></rect>
  <circle id="circle" r="15" cx="15" cy="15" fill="red"></circle>
</svg>

<svg>
  <use id="shape" xlink:href="#rect"></use>
</svg>
```

The weird thing was, is that the `attributeName` was just `href`, but an `attributeNamespace` was present in the mutation object. So I decided to test this by just watching for `href` changes.

---

## Watch for just href changes

The following watches for just `href` attribute changes which works on things like `<a>` elements, but it is still **not** recognizing a change for the `<use>` element:

```js
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation);
  });
});

observer.observe(document.body, {
  subtree: true,
  attributes: true,
  attributeFilter: ['href']
});

document.querySelector('#shape').setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', '#circle');

console.log('No mutations will be logged');
```

```html
<svg display="none">
  <rect id="rect" height="30" width="30" fill="red"></rect>
  <circle id="circle" r="15" cx="15" cy="15" fill="red"></circle>
</svg>

<svg>
  <use id="shape" xlink:href="#rect"></use>
</svg>
```

---

## How can I watch for just changes to the xlink:href attribute?

Is this a namespace issue that has to due with svg's that I am unaware of? Or is it a bug with MutationObserver?

Comment: The MDN docs say that the `attributeFilter` list should be attribute names *without* namespaces.

Comment: To add to @Pointy's comment (since he's faster than I): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#MutationObserverInit

Comment: I see that you've tried that (I think); I don't have enough experience with it to know why that'd happen. Do you pick up changes to SVG node attributes like "cx" and "cy"?

Comment: @Pointy, I changed the `r` attribute on a circle and specified `r` in the `attributeFilter`, and it did log a mutation when I changed the attribute.

Comment: Hmm well if it were *me* I'd definitely start thinking "bug". Is it the same between Firefox and Chrome (if they both support it)?

Comment: @Pointy, it is performing the same in Firefox and Chrome. Maybe I need to do more testing, [the support is pretty high](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver)

Comment: @Pointy it's not a bug if Firefox and Chrome implement [the specification as written](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#mutationobserver) which clearly says no namespace is permitted. If you think that should change you need to start by getting the spec changed.

Comment: @RobertLongson well it's not my fight; I'm just a complete know-nothing commenter here :) I've read through that spec however and, after those 5 minutes of intense study, it's still not super-clear that namespaced attribute changes should not be filterable, but I'll take your word for it. (I do see where it says that the namespace shouldn't be included in the filter list, but the description about how name matching should work when an actual mutation occurs is a little vague to me.)

Comment: I think the relevant normative statement in the spec is in step 3.1 of the [queue a mutation record](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#queueing-a-mutation-record) algorithm, where it says that if *attributeFilter* is present, and if *attributeFilter* does not contain *name* or ***namespace* is non-null**, then do not append an observer to *interested observers*. Notice the “if… ***namespace* is non-null**” part. In the namespaced `xlink:href` case, *namespace* is non-null, so no observer gets appended to *interested observers*.